# How to make a Tab widget that has 3 shaped boxes side by side with flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabs

I tried using tabs widget in **Flutter**.I was able to do it, but there is no square shape boxes for me to customize the tab widget,

and addition to this, it is required for me to do it not inside the appbar,
they even ask me to put that on the bottom as well which i suppose that bottombar will do right?

This is the sample that I saw that and I wanted to give it a try.

[image: Containers Tabs]

More specific, the tab on the top. I also want to interchange it and using at the bottom, if necessary, but I couldn't get the square shape on container.

UPDATE

here is the alternative i did, but the problem is that its scrollable which i am hoping to leave it as three boxes that is there and people can scroll from left to right,

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:survey/widgets/widgetlist.dart';


class pinsurvey extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _pinsurveyState createState() => _pinsurveyState();
}

class _pinsurveyState extends State<pinsurvey> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _controller;
  AnimationController _animationControllerOn;
  AnimationController _animationControllerOff;

  Animation _colorTweenBackgroundOn;
  Animation _colorTweenBackgroundOff;
  Animation _colorTweenForegroundOn;
  Animation _colorTweenForegroundOff;

  int _currentIndex = 0;
  int _prevControllerIndex = 0;
  double _aniValue = 0.0;
  double _prevAniValue = 0.0;
  List textlist = [
    "CURRENT PINNED",
    "NEWLY CREATED",
    "ARCHIVED",
  ];


  Color _foregroundOn = Colors.white;
  Color _foregroundOff = Colors.black;
  Color _backgroundOn = Colors.blue;
  Color _backgroundOff = Colors.grey[300];
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  List _keys = [];
  bool _buttonTap = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    for (int index = 0; index < textlist.length; index++) {

      _keys.add(new GlobalKey());
    }
    _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: textlist.length);
    _controller.animation.addListener(_handleTabAnimation);
    _controller.addListener(_handleTabChange);
    _animationControllerOff =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 75));
    _animationControllerOff.value = 1.0;
    _colorTweenBackgroundOff =
        ColorTween(begin: _backgroundOn, end: _backgroundOff)
            .animate(_animationControllerOff);
    _colorTweenForegroundOff =
        ColorTween(begin: _foregroundOn, end: _foregroundOff)
            .animate(_animationControllerOff);
    _animationControllerOn =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150));
    _animationControllerOn.value = 1.0;
    _colorTweenBackgroundOn =
        ColorTween(begin: _backgroundOff, end: _backgroundOn)
            .animate(_animationControllerOn);
    _colorTweenForegroundOn =
        ColorTween(begin: _foregroundOff, end: _foregroundOn)
            .animate(_animationControllerOn);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            title: Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 60,
              child: Image.asset(imgtit2),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
              Text("PIN A NEW SURVEY",style: txtttitsize),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Container(
                  height: 49.0,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: textlist.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                            key: _keys[index],
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                            child: ButtonTheme(
                                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                  animation: _colorTweenBackgroundOn,
                                  builder: (context, child) => FlatButton(
                                      color: _getBackgroundColor(index),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(1.0)),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _buttonTap = true;
                                          _controller.animateTo(index);
                                          _setCurrentIndex(index);
                                           _scrollTo(index);
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Text(textlist[index])),
                                )));
                      })),
              Flexible(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(textlist[0]),
                      Text(textlist[1]),
                      Text(textlist[2]),
                    ],
                  )),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }

  _handleTabAnimation() {
    _aniValue = _controller.animation.value;
    if (!_buttonTap && ((_aniValue - _prevAniValue).abs() < 1)) {
      _setCurrentIndex(_aniValue.round());
    }
    _prevAniValue = _aniValue;
  }
  _handleTabChange() {
    if (_buttonTap) _setCurrentIndex(_controller.index);
    if ((_controller.index == _prevControllerIndex) ||
        (_controller.index == _aniValue.round())) _buttonTap = false;
    _prevControllerIndex = _controller.index;
  }
  _setCurrentIndex(int index) {
    if (index != _currentIndex) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
     _triggerAnimation();
      _scrollTo(index);
    }
  }
  _triggerAnimation() {
    _animationControllerOn.reset();
    _animationControllerOff.reset();
   _animationControllerOn.forward();
    _animationControllerOff.forward();
  }

  _scrollTo(int index) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    RenderBox renderBox = _keys[index].currentContext.findRenderObject();
    double size = renderBox.size.width;
    double position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx;
    double offset = (position + size / 2) - screenWidth / 2;
    if (offset < 0) {
      renderBox = _keys[0].currentContext.findRenderObject();
      position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx;
      if (position > offset) offset = position;
    } else {
      renderBox = _keys[textlist.length - 1].currentContext.findRenderObject();
      position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx;
      size = renderBox.size.width;
      if (position + size < screenWidth) screenWidth = position + size;
      if (position + size - offset < screenWidth) {
        offset = position + size - screenWidth;
      }
    }
    _scrollController.animateTo(offset + _scrollController.offset,
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 150), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }

  _getBackgroundColor(int index) {
    if (index == _currentIndex) {
      return _colorTweenBackgroundOn.value;
    } else if (index == _prevControllerIndex) {
      return _colorTweenBackgroundOff.value;
    } else {
      return _backgroundOff;
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Please check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for the tip i updated the question

Comment: You haven't shared your code and your question is still very difficult to understand. That's likely the main reason you haven't received any responses.

Comment: thanks i have updated the post with my code,, this is just an alternative but i want it something that is not scrollabel or it fits exactly on the screen like the sample first picture